# Should we check a function not empty before applied with std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function, stdbind

```
std::function<void(bool)> f;
std::function<void()> binded_f = std::bind(f, true);
std::cout << (f != nullptr) << " " << (binded_f != nullptr) << "\n";
f(true);
binded_f();
```

Above code gave output `0 1`, and `binded_f()` crash with `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE7B63A388 in: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_function_call at memory location 0x00000096960FA660. occurred` in MSVC.

Seems calling the null function `f` is fine, while after `std::bind` applied, it will crash. What should we do? Do we need check a function before binded?

Answer (score 3):

> Seems calling the `null` function `f` is fine, while after `std::bind`
> applied, it will crash. What should we do?

No, both

```
f(true);
binded_f();
```

will through exception, and you see the exception from the first function call (i.e. `f(true);`) itself.
From *cppreference.com* [std::function<R(Args...)>::operator()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()#Exceptions)

> **Exceptions**

> `std::bad_function_call` if `*this` does not store a callable
> function target, i.e. `!*this == true`.

Meaning, the call of `f` is clearly an exception.

Also for [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Exceptions)

> **Exceptions**
>
> Only throws **if construction of `std::decay<F>::typ`e from**
> **`std::forward<F>(f)` throws**, or any of the constructors for
> `std::decay<Arg_i>::type` from the corresponding
> `std::forward<Arg_i>(arg_i)` throws where `Arg_`i is the ith type and
> `arg_i` is the ith argument in `Args... args`.

Since the construction of `f` throws/ fails, the binded object will also through exception upon call.

---

> Do we need to check a function before binded?

Yes, for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::bad_function_call` already happens at `f(true)`.

You need to check if `f` holds a function on both cases when calling `f` and before you call `std::bind` on it.

`std::bind` expects a [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)  object and `std::function<void(bool)> f` itself is a callable object. But calling `f` is only valid if it holds a target, as it will forward the call using [std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to the stored target when `f` is called.

`std::function<void()> binded_f` holds a target that will call the stored copy of `f` with `true` as the first argument, so `binded_f` itself holds a valid target, but that target, when it tries to call `f` with `true` will fail result into a `std::bad_function_call` because `f` does not hold a valid target.

This becomes more obvious if you replace the bind with a lambda.

```
std::function<void(bool)> f;
std::function<void()> binded_f = [f]() {
   return f(true);
};

std::cout << (f != nullptr) << " " << (binded_f != nullptr) << "\n";
f(true);
binded_f();
```